# How to pass multiple arguments?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, command-line-arguments, syntax, arguments

How to pass *multiple* paramaters for `Start a program` action in Windows Task Scheduler for a batch file? There's no built-in syntax hint...

Comment: When I write the whole command line to "Program/script" field Scheduler auotmatically moves all arguments to an arguments field during saving the task, with all nesessary quotes... for you not so?

Comment: @Akina I haven't tried that. I'd add it as an answer if so.

Comment: Try, and if so - add it into your answer as alternative variant. One solid answer is better than 2 separate ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the same as how you'd pass them in command prompt:

- Separate the arguments by space,
- Enclose each argument with double quotes, `"` if [metacharacter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter)s are involved

As in:

```
"super user:" 810934
```

[image: How the Arguments Should Look Like in the Textbox]

---

Alternatively you could simply add the arguments next to `Program/script` as [Akina](https://superuser.com/users/910710/akina) [points out](https://superuser.com/questions/1358089/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments/1358090#comment2039224_1358089):

```
D:\my_script.bat "super user:" 810934
```

[image: simply add the arguments next to <code>Program/script</code>]

After selecting <kbd>OK</kbd> the following should be prompted:

[image: Resolved Arguments]