# Is there a way to execute a shortcut on a schedule

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to execute a desktop shortcut on a scheduler? I've tried the task scheduler but when I specify the shortcut, it changes it automatically to the underlying exe file.

Comment: See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/427268/how-to-execute-shortcut-from-command-line-in-windows-7/427275) link.  Also.. I haven't tried it for the scheduler.. but there is an environment variable called PATHEXT.  If you permanently add .LNK to the system version of the variable, the scheduler might very well launch it.  I am too lazy to test it.  Also.. this could potentially be a way for baddies to launch things too but it is what you asked for.  If you can't, then try cmd.exe /c "start .... " with the lnk after the change.

Answer (score 2):

**Requested Way**

To accomplish what you requested, when you add the Action to the scheduled task, you need to enter the following (here I am launching PuTTY):

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\username\desktop\putty.lnk"
```

This will accomplish what you requested. (Note: the /c "C:\users\username\desktop\putty.lnk" goes into the "Add Arguments:" field.

**The Better Way**

What you are describing is normal behavior, and is what I would expect to happen. To give a bit of information, when you run a shortcut you are actually running the executable and possibly specifying additional parameters. To verify this right click on the shortcut in question | Select Properties and look at the "Target" field. For example this is the target for my Chrome shortcut:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

If you need to add additional parameters to the scheduled task, you can add in the Add Arguments (Optional) field. For example I have a PowerShell script set up as a scheduled task and add the **-ExecutionPolicy Bypass** parameter in the Add arguments field.

[image: Scheduled Task]

Here is an [additional resource](https://superuser.com/questions/1358089/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments) if you need to pass multiple arguments in the scheduled task.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question even if it is the right way to go about things.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You are correct, I have edited my answer to give both the requested and the better way.